# How to retrieve addresses affected by block?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, etherscan

I need to scan each block and extract addresses affected in the block.
The address is affected when funds (ETH, tokens, etc.) are sent to or from the address or involved in any other transaction.

As far as I understand, an address can be affected also by so-called internal transactions (calls to smart contracts or similar).

What is the preferred way to retrieve this information?
AFAIK, the standard node does not provide information about internal transactions (please, correct me if I am wrong).

Data providers like Etherscan require a user to know the addresses of interest in advance which is not the case for me.

I appreciate any input.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there event logs that are emitted by known contracts that you can query and have the addresses as an indexed field in those events?

Comment: @MShakeG, if you are asking me, unfortunately, I do not know. I have never worked with the event logs.